# How to avoid variable undefined which making menu activation?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code structure like this:

```
class clsName{

    public $data = [];

    public function menu1(){
        $this->data['active']['menu1'] = 'a_p_t';
    }

    public function menu2(){
        $this->data['active']['menu2'] = 'a_p_t';
    }

    public function makeMenu(){
        return "<ul>
                    <li class='".$this->data['active']['menu1']."'>menu1</li>
                    <li class='".$this->data['active']['menu2']."'>menu2</li>
                </ul>";
    }
}
```

In reality, there are 20 items in the menu .. so, I always get 19 undefined warnings. Because always only one of them is activated. So, any idea how can I avoid those warnings?

An ugly way is to define all array-items (all keys of menu) inside each method, but I'm looking for a better appraoch.

Comment: You can check variable by `??` so your code would be like `<li class='".$this->data['active']['menu1'] ?? '' ."'>menu1</li>`

Comment: @NikleshRaut Very good .. thank you

Comment: @NikleshRaut Noted that apparently without parentheses it won't work correctly. So it would be written this way: `<li class='".($this->data['active']['menu1'] ?? '') ."'>menu1</li>`